# Does Melissa Shield ever appear outside the movie?

Tags: my-hero-academia

AFAIR, in the first 3 seasons of the My Hero Academia anime, Melissa Shield never appears. How about the manga? Does Melissa Shield ever appear outside the movie?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, **she does appear in the anime**, specifically in [Episode 58](https://bokunoheroacademia.fandom.com/wiki/Episode_58).

> [image: ![Blockquote]

She also appears in the spinoff volume [Two Heroes](https://bokunoheroacademia.fandom.com/wiki/Volume_Origin), which was released alongside the film.